# Visio Diagram Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visio, visio-services

I'm getting an error while trying to open a visio diagram on SharePoint 2010 library. Here is a screen shot of error.

[image]

Here is detail of error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeEndService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.GraphicsServer.IVisioGraphicsService.EndGetVectorDiagram(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.Administration.VisioGraphicsServiceApplicationProxy.GetVectorDiagram(VectorDiagramRequestContract vectorDiagramRequest)
   at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.ServiceWrapper.GetVectorDiagram(String visioFileUrl, Int32 pageNumber, Boolean disableRefresh, AddonDataSource[] dataSources)
   at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.GetDiagramAsyncTask.EndGetVectorData(IAsyncResult result)
```

And here is ULS log:

```
Failed to generate Raster diagram for file http://www.example.com/sites/xxx/Dashboards/CriticalDB.vdw Error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    
 at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.GraphicsServer.RefreshEngine.Refresh()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.GraphicsServer.RefreshEngine.CreateOutputDiagram(Boolean disableRefresh)    
 at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.GraphicsServer.Core.VectorizeDiagram()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.GraphicsServer.Core.get_RasterDiagram()    
 at Microsoft.Office.Visio.Server.GraphicsServer.VisioGraphicsService.GetRasterDiagram(RasterDiagramRequestContract rasterDiagramRequest)
```

What can cause this problem? How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your Visio Service Application Pool have read/write permission to the content database where the drawing is located?

Comment: Visio Service Application is using farm admin credentials, so I think it has enough permissions. But I will check again.